# In Inno Setup, how do I center some text in the window?

Tags: inno-setup, centering, pascalscript

In Inno Setup, how do I center some text in the window?  I tried making it a `TLabel` and setting the `Alignment` to `taCenter` but it didn't have any effect.  I can set the `Left` and `Top` with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Alignment`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel.Alignment) property controls the horizontal placement of the text within the label. It's not used to position controls within their parent. Except [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel.Align) property (which stretches controls to given space), there is no way to center controls to their parents. But you can make a function for this:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure CenterInParent(Control: TControl);
begin
  if Assigned(Control) and Assigned(Control.Parent) then
  begin
    Control.Left := (Control.Parent.Width - Control.Width) div 2;
    Control.Top := (Control.Parent.Height - Control.Height) div 2;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  MyPage: TWizardPage;
  MyLabel: TLabel;
begin
  MyPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');

  MyLabel := TLabel.Create(MyPage);
  MyLabel.Parent := MyPage.Surface;
  MyLabel.Caption := 'Hello!';

  CenterInParent(MyLabel);
end;
```