# Inno Setup - how to center an animated gif in resized wizard

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to center my animated gif right in the middle of all pages in my installer ( `WizardSizePercent=150`) without using values.

Here is my code:

```pascal
var
  ParentForm: TSetupForm;

begin
  TimerID := 0;
  SlideID := 0;
  ContentHeight := ParentForm.Top + ParentForm.Height;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image1.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image2.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image3.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image4.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image5.bmp');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Image6.bmp');


  Panel := TPanel.Create(ParentForm);
  Panel.Parent := ParentForm;
  Panel.Left := 185;
  Panel.Top := ParentForm.Top + 130;
  Panel.Width := 1000;
  Panel.Height := 380;
  Panel.Visible := True;

  BackImage := TBitmapImage.Create(ParentForm);
  BackImage.Parent := Panel;
  BackImage.Width:= 1000;
  BackImage.Height:= 380;
  BackImage.Left := (Panel.Height - BackImage.Height) div 2;
  BackImage.Top := (Panel.Height - BackImage.Height) div 2;
  BackImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Image1.bmp'));
  StartSlideTimer;
end;
```

How do I have to change the values of `ContentHeight`, `Panel` and `BackImage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WizardSizePercent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsizepercent) (both explicit and implied by [`WizardStyle=modern`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardstyle)) apply only after the `InitializeWizard`. So the controls explicitly positioned in `InitializeWizard` can become misplaced afterwards.

Either position the image only after the [`WizardSizePercent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsizepercent) is applied. So e.g. in the [`CurPageChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged), not in `InitializeWizard`.

Or better, to have a more robust solution, that works e.g. even with [`WizardResizable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardresizable), respond to `WizardForm.OnResize` by updating the image coordinates (or rather the `Panel` coordinates – though I do not understand its purpose). For an example, see [Setting control width to half of custom page SurfaceWidth does not work correctly in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64695256/850848).

In many cases, you can also use `Anchors` property to have the control resize automatically. For some example, see [Inno Setup - aligning custom button with the Cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63481543/850848).

---

Also note that you cannot use constant coordinates. Your image would not center correctly on high DPI displays.  Either scale the coordinates – for that check for example [Inno Setup Placing image/control on custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696537/850848). Or in your case, it would be better, if you calculate the centered coordinates programmatically based on the image and window sizes – for that, check the [In Inno Setup, how do I center some text in the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25384671/850848)