# Setting control width to half of custom page SurfaceWidth does not work correctly in Inno Setup

Tags: width, inno-setup, pascalscript

I placed a `Panel` on my custom page and gave it a width of `SurfaceWidth`. Then I changed its width to `SurfaceWidth div 2`. Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot the new panel's width is definitely not equal to `SurfaceWidth div 2`. Why is that so?

Here's the code:

```pascal
[Setup]
WizardStyle=modern

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  Panel: TPanel;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TButton and others');
  Panel := TPanel.Create(Page);
  Panel.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth div 2;
  Panel.Left := 0;
  Panel.Height := 46;
  Panel.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
  Panel.Caption := 'TPanel';
  Panel.Color := clWindow;
  Panel.BevelKind := bkFlat;
  Panel.BevelOuter := bvNone; 
  Panel.ParentBackground := False;
  Panel.Parent := Page.Surface;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `akRight` in `Panel.Anchors` and `modern` [`WizardStyle`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardstyle) (or rather the 120 [`WizardSizePercent`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsizepercent) it implies). The wizard is scaled only after the `InitializeWizard`. With `akRight`, the panel width will grow linearly (not proportionally) with the wizard. There are solutions, but they depend on how you actually want the panel to behave in the resizable wizard (also implied by the `modern` style).

See also [Inno Setup - how to center an animated gif in resized wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63502238/850848).

If you want to keep the panel at half size, when the wizard is resized (either automatically due to `WizardSizePercent` or by the user due to [`WizardResizable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardresizable)), handle `WizardForm.OnResize`:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  Panel: TPanel;

procedure WizardFormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth div 2;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(
    wpWelcome, 'Custom wizard page controls', 'TButton and others');
  Panel := TPanel.Create(Page);
  Panel.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth div 2;
  // ...
  WizardForm.OnResize := @WizardFormResize;
end;
```

Make sure you do not set the `akRight` anchor.