# Long components descriptions in enlarged Inno Setup wizard

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to get this Martin Prikryl code to work in my Setup: [Long descriptions on Inno Setup components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867087/long-descriptions-on-inno-setup-components)

But when I put `WizardSizePercent=121` inside the `[Setup]` section, the code works, but it has some problem that causes the components caption to be overlapped by the `ComponentsList`.

And I tried to change the code below (The end of the original code) but it was no use. The only thing you can change by doing this is changing the height of the `WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height`.

Can anyone help me with this?

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  SetTimer(0, 0, 50, CreateCallback(@HoverTimerProc));

  CompLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  CompLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
  CompLabel.Left := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Left;
  CompLabel.Width := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Width;
  CompLabel.Height := ScaleY(32);
  CompLabel.Top :=
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top + WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height;
  CompLabel.AutoSize := False;
  CompLabel.WordWrap := True;

  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height :=
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
end;
```

Comment: See [Inno Setup - how to center an animated gif in resized wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63502238/850848).

Comment: I was able to change it, but when using `CurPageChanged`, the code makes a call every time I switch pages, with that it adds lots and lots of captions on the page.

I used the `procedure CurPageChanged(wpWelcome: Integer);` instead of `procedure InitializeWizard();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a boolean variable.
The `StopCall` variable starts with `false` and if it is `false`, it executes the code and then sets it to `true`.

So the next time `CurPageChanged` is executed, the value will be `true` and the code will not add a new caption.

```pascal
var StopCall: Boolean;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if StopCall = false then
    begin
      if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
        begin
          SetTimer(0, 0, 50, CreateCallback(@HoverTimerProc));

          CompLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
          CompLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage;
          CompLabel.Left := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Left;
          CompLabel.Width := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Width;
          CompLabel.Height := ScaleY(22);
          CompLabel.Top := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top + WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height;
          CompLabel.AutoSize := False;
          CompLabel.WordWrap := True;

          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Height - CompLabel.Height - ScaleY(8);
          StopCall := true;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You should have put only the position assignments to the `CurPageChanged`. The rest should have stayed in the `InitializeWizard`.

Comment: I tried, but I'm still new at it. 
Then the only way I could solve it was like this. 
But thank you very much, if it wasn't for your comment, I wouldn't have made it!